# An hard math problem with integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ A a differentiable function,such that exists $f''(x) $ with $f'(1)=2$ and $$f''(x)f'(x)+x+e^{x-1}\le 4$$ for any $x\in [0,1]$. Prove that $\int^1_0 (f'(x))^2 dx \ge 2/3+2/e$.

I found out by integrating $f''(x)f'(x)+x+e^{x-1}\le 4$ that
$$\int (f'(x))^2 dx\le 8x-x^2-2e^{x-1}.$$

Comment: You forgot to evaluate the right side at the limits $0,1$. After all, you have integrated the given inequality from $0$ to $1$, right?

Comment: The last "equation" makes no sense. On the left you have a number, and on the right you have a non constant function.

Comment: Yes.I am sorry I tape it wrong.

Comment: Can you help me to solve it?Please?@Tavish

Comment: Or anyone can help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plugging in $x=1$ we get that:
$$f''(1)f'(1)\le 2$$
and we are given that:
$$f'(1)=2$$

---

if we integrate:
$$\int f''(x)f'(x)\,dx+\int (x+e^{x-1})dx\le \int 4\,dx$$
which gives:
$$f'(x)^2+\frac{x^2}2+e^{x-1}\le 4x+C$$
plugging in $x=1$ we get:
$$4+\frac12+1\le 4+C$$
so we must have that $C=\frac32$ leaving us with the expression:
$$f'(x)^2\le\frac32+4x-\frac{x^2}2-e^{x-1}$$
integrating both sides between $0$ and $1$ yields:
$$\int_0^1f'(x)^2\,dx\le\int_0^1\left(\frac32+4x-\frac{x^2}2-e^{x-1}\right)\,dx$$
and I will leave you to figure it out from here

Comment: Alright @Henry Lee

Comment: I would appreciate if you could upvote and accept as answer if this was useful @mathfull2309

Comment: I know how to solve it know.

Comment: Yes.I accepted the answer but it told me that I need at least 15 reputation to vote @Henry Lee.If you could help me with a vota at the problem I will can probably to vote your answer too.